# Multiple Javascript alerts not displaying in Windows Store App

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

Multiple alerts are not working in windows store apps. If you put multiple alerts only the last one gets displayed. Is there any workaround for this. Like in the below example only c is displayed.

```
function displayAlerts(){
 alert("a");
 alert("b");
 alert("c");
}
```

Comment: in every case where there is multiple alerts it dosent work.

Comment: Why are you using alert? You should never use alert. Are you trying to use this for debugging purposes? Or for actual UI?

Comment: Its a hybrid app and the alerts are put in the javascript layer. Only in windows 8 multiple alerts do not come. This issue is not observed in windows phone 8.

Comment: That didn't really answer the question, though. If you're using them for debugging, you can use console.log to output debugging info to the JS console, or the "debugger" statement to act as a breakpoint or assert.

If you're using alerts as actual UI, you should stop that. They're problematic for many reasons and use of them is discouraged on all platforms (and in some, like WWAHost, explicitly disabled/deprecated). There are lots of libraries (like jQueryUI, Bootstrap, etc) with support for better behaved HTML modal dialogs, and for which you can customize the UI to match your site/app.

Answer (score 1):

The alert function is not avaible natively on HTML Windows Apps

You have to use something like this:

```
var msgBox = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message);
msgBox.showAsync();
```

And if you want to display multiple message you have to do something like this

```
   var msgBox = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("1");
    msgBox.showAsync().then(function () {;
        msgBox = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("2");
        msgBox.showAsync().then(function () {
            msgBox = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("3");
            msgBox.showAsync();
        })
    });
```

because only one message can be displayed simultaneously, you have to wait that the user confirm each message to display the next one.

Comment: I cant use native methods. This is a hybrid app  and it has to be the javascript alert.

Comment: You dont have a choice. You can create an abstraction layer to provide the same methods to target different platforms.

In this awsome liberarie https://github.com/gleborgne/winjscontrib ( :) ) we provide a big number of controls/convertors/bindings system and multiple abstractions layers to target Native apps on Windows 8 and Android and iOS apps with Cordova. 
In the namespace  WinJSContrib.Alerts  we have a method called message that provide this fonctionality.

The API documentation is still under construction but it is available (http://gleborgne.github.io/winjscontrib/api/index.html)